# Check, whether an array contains an object with id that matches list of ids

Tags: javascript, arrays

is there an elegant way to determine, whether an array like this:

```
[
  {id: 1, value: false},
  {id: 2, value: true},
  {id: 3, value: false},
  {id: 4, value: true},
  {id: 5, value: true}
]
```

contains an item with an id that is listed in another array like this:

```
[1,5]
```

In this case only these values should be returned:

```
  {id: 1, value: false},
  {id: 5, value: true}
```

I was trying to use `includes()`, but it's not working:

```
let array = [
  {id: 1, value: false},
  {id: 2, value: true},
  {id: 3, value: false},
  {id: 4, value: true},
  {id: 5, value: true}
];

array.includes([1,5])
```

Comment: `array.filter()` would work.

Comment: try `array.filter(( {id} ) => [1,5].includes(id));`

Comment: Do you really need to return matching items to use those later on? If so, you need to change your post title accordingly since it is misleading, as `true` or `false` is not enough for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you use a `Set`. Since you are searching your data for specific keys, this will have **much better performances** on large search arrays:

```js
const data = [
  {id: 1, value: false},
  {id: 2, value: true},
  {id: 3, value: false},
  {id: 4, value: true},
  {id: 5, value: true}
]

const search = (data, terms) => {
  terms = new Set(terms)
  return data.filter(({ id }) => terms.has(id))
}

console.log(search(data, [1, 5]))
```

Another note about performances. If your code is calling `search` with different terms many times, you can consider indexing your array in a `Map` (or an object):

```js
const data = [
  {id: 1, value: false},
  {id: 2, value: true},
  {id: 3, value: false},
  {id: 4, value: true},
  {id: 5, value: true}
]

const indexedData = new Map(data.map((el) => [el.id, el]))

const search = (...terms) => {
  return terms.map((id) => indexedData.get(id)).filter(e => e)
}

console.log(search(1, 5, 10))
```

The latest script will iterate only once through your whole data, and then complexity will be `o(n)`, `n` being your search terms.

EDIT: [Here's a benchmark of all solutions for you to play with](https://jsperf.com/stackoverflow-find-by-index/1)

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) combined with [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to generate a new array containing only the items that have an `id` included in `ids`:

```js
const array = [
  {id: 1, value: false},
  {id: 2, value: true},
  {id: 3, value: false},
  {id: 4, value: true},
  {id: 5, value: true}
];
const ids = [1, 5];

const filteredArray = array.filter((item) => ids.includes(item.id));
console.log(filteredArray);
```

Comment: Even though this solution is clear. It is _really_ slow for large array or repeted use, I've made a [benchmark](https://jsperf.com/stackoverflow-find-by-index/1) for this :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. My solution is a good option only if the arrays are small.

Comment: It's only the array of ids which has to be small for this to be efficient.  A `filter` will have to loop over the main array in any case.

Comment: @ScottSauyet — Not if you index the main array, with a `Map` for instance. [See details on my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60253739/6320039).

Comment: @UlysseBN: Yes, I saw that.  And for many cases, it's the right technique.  It's main gain, though, only exists if you can predefine your search map.  And the relative efficiencies have more to do with the number of ids.  Your  `1000 / 50` perf test is only one possibility.  The sample in the question is only `5 / 2`.  Without knowing the realistic data size or whether caching a map is feasible, it's very hard to determine best performance.

Comment: Hence the explanation that goes along saying that search array length and main array length and use are important. If you feel that my answer is not clear enough in your opinion, feel free to edit :).

Comment: @UlysseBN: My comment here was just to add a caveat to your comment on this answer, or even more precisely on Alberto's gloss on your comment.  Your own answer seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
const data = [
  {id: 1, value: false},
  {id: 2, value: true},
  {id: 3, value: false},
  {id: 4, value: true},
  {id: 5, value: true}
];

const searchTerm = [1,5];

const result = data.filter((dataObject) => {

    // dataObject will be each item in the data array;
    return searchTerm.includes(dataObject.id)}
})
```

Comment: `filter` doesn't need the `dataObject`, just a truthy or falsy value. Hence here you could return the result of `includes`.